# xml Element Delete form xml file wp8

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, linq-to-xml

Hello i try to delete xml element but code is run successfully but when i am check xml file data is not deleted 
Here is my Xml Data How to delete 
in xml file pageno is different Please Help

```
   <data>
  <Bookmarkdata>
    <Bookname>thepdftest</Bookname>
    <Bookid>57d86c55-1d9a-49d0-8b60-acdc0c283d24</Bookid>
    <Pageno>1</Pageno>
  </Bookmarkdata>
  <Bookmarkdata>
    <Bookname>thepdftest</Bookname>
    <Bookid>57d86c55-1d9a-49d0-8b60-acdc0c283d24</Bookid>
    <Pageno>2</Pageno>
  </Bookmarkdata>
  <Bookmarkdata>
    <Bookname>thepdftest</Bookname>
    <Bookid>57d86c55-1d9a-49d0-8b60-acdc0c283d24</Bookid>
    <Pageno>3</Pageno>
  </Bookmarkdata>
</data>
```

Here is my code

1.this is not retutn any error but not at remove

```
 doc.Descendants("Bookmarkdata")
    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Pageno") == pageno)
    .Remove();
```

and i am try to with two where condition using and that return a error

```
 doc.Descendants("Bookmarkdata")
    .Where((x => (string)x.Attribute("Pageno") == pageno) &&
           (x => (string)x.Attribute("Bookname") == bookname))
    .Remove();
```

This is my Full code

```
private void DeleteBookMark(string bookname, string pageno)
{

    using (IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (!file.FileExists("BookmarkFile.xml"))
        {
            StreamResourceInfo sr_en = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources\\BookmarkFile.xml", UriKind.Relative));
            using (BinaryReader br_en = new BinaryReader(sr_en.Stream))
            {
                byte[] data1 = br_en.ReadBytes((int)sr_en.Stream.Length);
                //Write the file.
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(file.CreateFile("BookmarkFile.xml")))
                {
                    bw.Write(data1);
                    bw.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        // work with file at isolatedstorage
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("BookmarkFile.xml", FileMode.Open, file))
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream, LoadOptions.None);

            doc.Descendants("Bookmarkdata")
                .Where((x => (string)x.Attribute("Pageno") == pageno) && (x => (string)x.Attribute("Bookname") == bookname))
                .Remove();


            // prevent xml file from doubling nodes
            if (stream.CanSeek)
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            doc.Save(stream);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two lambdas which you are comparing with `&&`. Lambda is an anonymous method - its not a result of method execution. So, you are trying to apply conditional AND on methods, which gives you error.

`Where` operator accepts one delegate which should return boolean value. Here is correct syntax:

```
 doc.Descendants("Bookmarkdata")
    .Where(x => (string)x.Element("Pageno") == pageno && 
                (string)x.Element("Bookname") == bookname)
    .Remove();
```

NOTE: Both `<Pageno>` and `<Bookname>` are elements, not attributes.

Comment: this is not removing any element may be problem in this code when i am removing this code that return a error 
 if (stream.CanSeek)
                        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    doc.Save(stream);

Comment: @NishantChandwani That is removing all matching elements from `doc`. You have another problems in your code. What error you have with stream? Provide error details

Comment: when i am remove this code  if (stream.CanSeek) stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); doc.Save(stream); return a error 
the error is xml gatting time :Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 18, position 10.
Debug time i am check a doc file not remove any element Please Help

Comment: @NishantChandwani you have invalid xml. Make sure you have valid data in xml file when you are opening it. If data is invalid then you can't load file into `XDocument`

Comment: i am sure data is there , debug time i have check data is there . and remove code and then check , Not delete any data what should i do

Comment: @NishantChandwani OK, I found problem - `Pageno` and `Bookname` are *elements*, not *attributes*. Updated code

Comment: i will attach image befor delete data and after delete data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49802/discussion-between-nishant-chandwani-and-sergey-berezovskiy)